# Codeigniter a simple way to get config-like array from cache folder

Tags: php, arrays, oop, codeigniter, global-variables

I have some data in array format which I wrote to a file in `application/cache` folder.
Format is:

```
$extra_data['some_key'] = 'some_data';
```

It is not directly about site config so I don't want to put it in `application/config`. Yet, in some cases, I need to reach this `$extra_data` inside the controller or model.

What I do is,

1) define variable in controller

```
class pages_model extends CI_Model
{
  var $extra_data;
```

2) inclulde the cache file and associate it with above variable,

```
  function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     @include_once APPPATH . "cache/extra_data.php";
     $this->extra_data = $extra_data;
  }
```

3) get the class variable as variable then use it:

```
function func_name()
{
  $extra_data = $this->extra_data;
```

This is the way I am using, but I am not sure that it is the correct or efficient way.

Thanks for any idea and suggesstion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you create a file in config folder that is called cache.php
in the file just put the data like this

```
$config['some_key'] = 'some_data';
```

then you can use this code in your construct

```
    $this->load->config('cache', TRUE);
    $extra_data = $this->config->item('cache')
```

I know its not config thing,  but since you are placing them on separate file it will be better way to use them

Comment: if no more answers follow i will have to eventually use this  way.

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the Loader library with a cache()?

Then you can call it like:

```
$this->load->cache('extra_data');
```

**libraries/MY_Loader.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    /* Load custom cache values */
    function cache($str = '') {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $data = array();
        $path = APPATH . "cache/{$str}.php";
        if (file_exists($path)) {

            include $path;
            $data = $extra_data;

        }

        $CI->$str = $data;

    }
```

}

Comment: Out of curiosity why call `file_get_contents($path)` rather than `file_exists($path)`?